# Javascript TypeError: xxx is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Friends I came to a bit of problem. Everything was working fine before. But I can't rectify why it starts giving me such error.
Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
function newSupplier() {
    $('div#AddSupplier div.msg').html('').hide();
    $('div#AddSupplier div.loader').show();
    registerSupplier($('div#AddSupplier table.frm :input').serialize()).done(function (a) {
        if (a.Msg) {
            $('div#AddSupplier div.msg').html(a.Msg).removeClass('success').addClass('error').fadeIn();
        }
        else if (a.supid) {
            $('div#AddSupplier div.msg').html('Supplier <span class="l2">' + a.supid + '</span> Registered').removeClass('error').addClass('success').fadeIn();
            $('div#AddSupplier table.frm :input').val('');
        }
    }).always(function () {
        $('div#AddSupplier div.loader').hide();
    }).fail(function () {
        $('div#AddSupplier div.msg').html(errMsgNet).removeClass('success').addClass('error').fadeIn();
    });
}
```

And here is the code of `registerSupplier()` function:

```
function registerSupplier(dataToPost) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jsonpath + 'Json.ashx?method=RegisterSupplier',
        data: dataToPost
    });
}
```

And here is the complete JS file: http://preview.myignou.com/Docs/jScript.js

Related HTML

```
<div id="ViewOrder">
   <h2>View Order Details</h2>
   <div class="tab-content">
      <table class="frm">
         <tr>
            <td><label>Enter Order Number</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="orderNumber" onkeyup="$('#ViewOrder>div>div').fadeOut();" /><input type="button" class="but1 m-side" value="OK" onclick="LoadMaterialOrder();"/></td>
            <td>
               <div class="process">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <div>
         <div class="border shadow m-tb">
            <h2 class="header">Order Details</h2>
            <div id="orderDetails" class="tab-content">
               <table class="frm">
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Supplier</label></td>
                     <td><select id="newSupplier" name="supplier"></select></td>
                     <td class="r-align"><input type="button" value="Load Suppliers" onclick="loadSuppliers('#newSupplier')" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Order Date</label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="orderDate" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Delivery Date</label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="deliveryDate" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Cancel Date</label></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="cancelDate" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Payment Due Mark</label></td>
                     <td><input id="payDue2" type="checkbox" name="isPayDue" /><label for="payDue2">Yes</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><label>Remember Mark</label></td>
                     <td><input id="remark2" type="checkbox" name="isMarked" /><label for="remark2">Yes</label></td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
            <table class="footer-buttons">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <div class="msg"></div>
                     <div class="loader" style="display:none;"><img alt="loader" src="CSS/Images/loader.gif" /></div>
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="button" class="but1 sub-but" value="Save Changes" onclick=""/><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
         <br />
         <div class="border shadow m-tb">
            <h2 class="header">Payment Records</h2>
            <div id="paymentHistory" class="tab-content">
               <table class="tab pay-his">
                  <tr class="th">
                     <td></td>
                     <td>Trans#</td>
                     <td>Date</td>
                     <td>Comment</td>
                     <td>Type</td>
                     <td>Credit</td>
                     <td>Debit</td>
                     <td>Balance</td>
                     <td>Associated Agent</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><input type="radio" name="paySelect" /></td>
                     <td>101-1</td>
                     <td>12-12-12</td>
                     <td>Abclk lask aa</td>
                     <td>Credit</td>
                     <td>500</td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>500.00</td>
                     <td>Shashwat Tripathi</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><input type="radio" name="paySelect" /></td>
                     <td>101-2</td>
                     <td>12-12-12</td>
                     <td>Shashwat Tripathi</td>
                     <td>Debit</td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>500</td>
                     <td>500.00</td>
                     <td>Sudhir</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><input type="radio" name="paySelect" /></td>
                     <td>101-3</td>
                     <td>12-12-12</td>
                     <td>Shashwat Tripathi</td>
                     <td>Credit</td>
                     <td>500</td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>500.00</td>
                     <td>Sudhir Gaur</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
               <br />
               <input type="button" class="but2" value="Edit" 
                  onclick="$('#ViewOrder #payEdit').slideDown(function () { $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#paymentHistory').offset().top-20 }, 500); });" /><input type="button" class="but2 m-side" value="Delete" />
               <div id="payEdit" class="border m-tb shadow" style="display:none;">
                  <h2 class="header">Edit Payment</h2>
                  <div class="tab-content">
                     <table class="frm">
                        <tr>
                           <td><label>Date</label></td>
                           <td><input type="text" name="date" placeholder="dd-mm-yy"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td><label>Type</label></td>
                           <td>
                              <select name="type">
                                 <option>Credit</option>
                                 <option>Debit</option>
                                 <option>Expense</option>
                              </select>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td><label>Amount</label></td>
                           <td><input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="धनराशी..." /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td><label>Comment</label></td>
                           <td><textarea name="comment" rows="4" cols="10"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td><input type="button" class="but1" value="Save Changes" /><input type="button" class="but2 m-side" onclick="$('#payEdit').slideUp();" value="Cancel" /></td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <br />
               <h2>Register New Payment</h2>
               <hr />
               <div id="newMatOrderPayment">
                  <table class="frm">
                     <tr>
                        <td><label>Date</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="date" placeholder="dd-mm-yy" /></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><label>Type</label></td>
                        <td>
                           <select name="type">
                              <option>Credit</option>
                              <option>Debit</option>
                              <option>Expense</option>
                           </select>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><label>Amount</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="धनराशी..." /></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><label>Comment</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="comment" rows="4" cols="10"></textarea></td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
            <table class="footer-buttons">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <div class="msg"></div>
                     <div class="loader" style="display:none;"><img alt="loader" src="CSS/Images/loader.gif" /></div>
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="button" class="but1" value="Register Payment" onclick=""/><input type="button" class="but2" onclick="$('#NewMatOrderPayment :text').val('');" value="Reset" /></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="AddSupplier">
   <h2>Register New Suppiler</h2>
   <div class="tab-content">
      <table class="frm">
         <tr>
            <td><label>Supplier ID</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="supId" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><label>Contact Number</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="contact" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><label>Address</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="address" cols="10" rows="4"></textarea></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><label>Email address</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><label>City</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <table class="footer-buttons">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div class="msg"></div>
            <div class="loader" style="display:none;"><img alt="loader" src="CSS/Images/loader.gif" /></div>
         </td>
         <td><input type="button" class="but1 sub-but" value="Register" onclick="newSupplier();"/><input type="reset" value="रीसेट" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

If I am calling this function directly from FF and Firebug console then It is getting called.
**But on button click I am getting error `TypeError: newSupplier is not a function`**

Please ask me If u need additional code.

Comment: Starting with the obvious: are you certain you added the script to the page, and are you certain it has loaded before you try to call `newSupplier();` ?  Perhaps post your html page as well, if it's not too long.

Comment: can you provide the html code, maybe you have an element with id *newSupplier* ?

Comment: yes @JcFx. I am very sure about it. Coz I have placed all javscript in a single file. All other function are being called. function `newSupplier()` can be called from FF and firebug console and also appears in intellisense of Firebug.

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano.. yeah may be.. let me check it first.. It it is not.. then I will give u complete HTML code

Comment: So the problem seems to be some kind of name conflict, as @CrisimIlNumenoreano` says. Please post your HTML if you can.

Comment: @JcFx @CrisimIlNumenoreano hmm.. I have a `select` element in HTML. Sorry to all. I could not understand the issue.

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi if the issue is resolved i'm really glad to have helped

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano But changing the name of function or id of select can make me towards more errors. Is there an alternate way..?? And I am little confused. If we can't access HTML element directly with id like `someId.someActionOrProperty` in javscript then why calling `newSupplier()` is getting conflict with an element of same ID..??

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi in IE, not sure about FF and chrome but i suppose so, you **can** access *some* properties with `someId.someActionOrProperty` but not from the FF console.

remain the fact you need to change one of your object name/id

Answer (score 25, accepted):

the first select tag in your html code has ID *newSupplier* just like the name of the function. some browsers can access the node elements just by specifying the ID in the js code and then the function defined is overridden by the element in the DOM.

you need to rename the function name or the element ID.

Comment: FYI, i just ran into a similar issue, though in my case i had a var (instead of a function) with the same name as an HTML div id.